# Read the Serial port of the Android/iOS with Cordova Phonegap plugin

Tags: android, ios, cordova, plugins, phonegap

Is there a plugin out there that is up to date for reading/writing to the serial port of Android/iOS. I have only found old out dated plugins. Is anyone aware of something that is up to date?

Comment: There is no serial port to read/write on iOS devices.

Comment: @Paulw11, thanks. What about a Cordova Plugin for Andriod?